# Edit beamerbaseboxes.sty to create square corners

Tags: beamer, rounded-corners

I came across [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102136/can-i-manipulate-the-rounded-ness-of-blocks) answer, which shows how to edit the `beamerbaseboxes.sty` file to increase the "rounded-ness" of the corners of boxes, when using the "rounded" boxes innertheme. In this answer, the author changed number values like `\pgfpathqcurveto`, `\pgflineto`, and `\pgfpoint`.

I would like to know what number values to use to obtain completely square corners (no rounded-ness). I want to do this *without* using the "rectangle" innertheme, so that I can keep the shadows provided by the rounded theme.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Yes, pgf is correct. Thanks. As for your first comment, an MWE is difficult in this case since it is a question about editing base files in the beamer package.

Comment: `rectangle` can be used with `shadows` option no?

Comment: @percusse: Evidently not. There is this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176337/shadow-of-a-non-rounded-block-in-beamer, which creates rectangular boxes with shadows. But it is a little more involved than what I am looking for, and, most importantly, did not preserve the other aspects of the Boadilla theme (which I like). So I believe the minimal solution should just be to change these number values in the indicated style file so that the rounded theme applies zero roundness.

Answer (score 1):

**Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176356/36296**

You can easily use the answer you linked in your comment together with the `Boadilla` theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\tikzset{beamer@color/.style={fill=none,top color=tcbcol@back,bottom color=tcbcol@back}}

\tcbset{beamer/.style={skin=beamer,boxrule=0mm,titlerule=1mm,toptitle=0.5mm,arc=2mm,fonttitle=\bfseries,drop fuzzy shadow=black}}

\tcbset{
tcbeamer/.style={
  beamer,
  width=\textwidth+3pt,
  enlarge left by=-3pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  left=1pt,
  right=1pt,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  toptitle=0pt,
  bottomtitle=-1pt,
  }
}

\newenvironment<>{tcexampleblock}[1]
  {\begin{actionenv}#2\begin{tcolorbox}[
    adjusted title=#1,
    tcbeamer,
    colback=block body example.bg,
    colframe=block title example.bg,
    fonttitle=\large\color{block title example.fg}
    ]
  }
  {\end{tcolorbox}\end{actionenv}}

\newenvironment<>{tcalertblock}[1]
  {\begin{actionenv}#2\begin{tcolorbox}[
    adjusted title=#1,
    tcbeamer,
    colback=block body alerted.bg,
    colframe=block title alerted.bg,
    fonttitle=\large\color{block title alerted.fg},
    adjusted title=#1,
    ]
  }
  {\end{tcolorbox}\end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{exampleblock}{Test exampleblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{beamer} class.
\end{exampleblock}

\begin{tcexampleblock}{Test tcexampleblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{tcolorbox} package.
\end{tcexampleblock}

\begin{alertblock}{Test alertblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{beamer} class.
\end{alertblock}

\begin{tcalertblock}{Test tcalertblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{tcolorbox} package.
\end{tcalertblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code can be further simplified with the new tcolorbox inner theme (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-tcolorbox )

This theme allows you to have square boxes with shadows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\useinnertheme[rounded=false]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{exampleblock}{Test exampleblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{beamer} class.
\end{exampleblock}

\begin{alertblock}{Test alertblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{beamer} class.
\end{alertblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you also like to keep the colour gradient between the title and body, you can change the corner radius like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  arc=0mm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{exampleblock}{Test exampleblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{beamer} class.
\end{exampleblock}

\begin{alertblock}{Test alertblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{beamer} class.
\end{alertblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]